# Query in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to run a query on my User model, like this:

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["u_org != c_org and u_org == ?", current_web.role.id])
```

This is the older style for running queries and it is not working as well. Can you please help me to run it in rails 3. I have tried:

```
@user = User.where("u_org != c_org and u_org == ?", current_web.role.id).all
```

and the result was [].

**Update:**

I have removed `==` as per the answer and still the query returns `[]`. I have tried only with `@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["u_org = ?", current_web.role.id])` and the value is returned successfully but i want it to be `@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["u_org != c_org and u_org = ?", current_web.role.id])`

**Edit:**

Sample Data:

u_org = 1

c_org = null

current_web.role.id = 1

Comment: You have tried and...? There was an error, it didn't return expected result? You need to be more specific.

Comment: The first query would not work as well, see vinodadhikary answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, the only problem is your use of double equals `==`.  Try the not working well query as follows:

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["u_org != c_org and u_org = ?", current_web.role.id])
```

And similarly your second as follows:

```
@user = User.where("u_org != c_org and u_org = ?", current_web.role.id).all
```

Comment: It is still the same. Nothing happens.

Comment: If you're getting `[]` in return then the query executed without any errors.  You need to check your data.  You could start by having only one condition that returns records and then apply another condition.

Comment: I have tried with `@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["u_org = ?", 2])` and it returns the value, but when i use `u_org!=c_org` it shows [] and looking at database table there is 2 under u_org and null under c_org. Is the null doing something?

Comment: In `SQL`, you check for `NULL` using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. The `!=` and `=` operators do not work for `NULL`.

Comment: @sushilthe, that query should work just fine.  Please, post some sample data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of NULL, if you want all the users with `c_org` not equal to null use `c_org IS NOT NULL` and for `c_org` equalt to null use `c_org IS NULL`

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["c_org IS NOT NULL and u_org = ?", current_web.role.id])
```

Edited

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["(u_org != c_org OR c_org IS NULL) and u_org == ?", current_web.role.id])
```

Comment: I want `u_org != c_org` but the value of c_org is null

Comment: @sushilthe:- Check my Edited answer, i guess you want users whose having c_org is null or users who having c_org not same as u_org